# Save serializable object to registry in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, registry

I'm writing some C# .net code that saves some values to the registry.  It worked fine up until I wanted to save some binary data.

I have a `List<MyType>` object where `MyType` looks like this:

```
[Serializable] public class MyType
{
 public string s {get;set;}
 public string t {get;set;}
}
```

I get an error with the following code:

```
List<MyType> objectToSaveInRegistry = getList();
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(MySpecialKey, true);
registryKey.SetValue("MySpecialValueName", objectToSaveInRegistry , RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```

The error is: "The type of the value object did not match the specified Registry ValueKind or the object could not be properly converted."

What can I do so that I can save my object in the registry?

Comment: why do u want to save it in a registry.why not make it an xml file and save it.

Comment: @Srinivas, my object contains information about the configuration of an application I'm developing. Isn't the Windows Registry meant to be a place where application settings can be saved?

Comment: You are trying to pass a List<MyType> to a method that is essentially expecting a byte array.  You will need to convert your list to that kind of representation (either by serializing to a MemoryStream, or using a different serializer).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably need to serialize your object first with the help of the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and store it in a `byte` array which you then can pass to `SetValue`. I doubt that `SetValue` will serialize the object for you.

Quick example:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, objectToSaveInRegistry);
    var data = ms.ToArray();
    registryKey.SetValue("MySpecialValueName", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
}
```

Comment: @ChrisWue try this `ms.WriteByte(1); Console.WriteLine(ms.GetBuffer().Length + " " + ms.ToArray().Length)` Output:  `256 1`

Answer (score 4):

It's better to serialize/unserialize your object as a string. In the following example, I use XML serialization. The "value" variable is the list object to store in the registry.

```
// using Microsoft.Win32;
// using System.IO;
// using System.Text;
// using System.Xml.Serialization;

string objectToSaveInRegistry;

using(var stream=new MemoryStream())
{
    new XmlSerializer(value.GetType()).Serialize(stream, value);
    objectToSaveInRegistry=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}

var registryKey=Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("MySpecialKey", true);
registryKey.SetValue("MySpecialValueName", objectToSaveInRegistry, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store the primitive values and then hydrate a poco when the data is pulled opposed to storing the poco itself.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @IllidanS4: He'd store the individual properties of the object as individual keys and then rebuilt the object from those keys as opposed to storing the serialized object in a single key. The advantage would be that you could easily manipulate individual properties (assuming you map all the way down to the primitive types) - although this could also be seen as a disadvantage.

Comment: @ChrisWue And four years later, I would still not understand the answer's text. Nice!