# Where / how to store application parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am building an application that is quite dynamic in nature (a lot of metadata coming from a database for example) and I want to store application parameters in a separate file. An example of a parameter is the column width of a certain column in a view.

I was thinking of creating a *Resources* file, but they can only store strings. *Settings* is not an option, because what I want to store are application parameters, not user settings.

What could be a good approach?

Comment: How about `app.config`?

Comment: @dialer could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sometimes an `app.config` file pops up in your C# project, it's an 'Executable Configuration'. It resides in the same folder as the `exe` (i.e. admin rights required when deployed). It is used to store user-independent settings. For non-admin modifiable settings, `Settings.settings` is the right choice. Create with `Add Item - Application Configuration File`. Often used for database connections and such. It is simlar to java's `properties`, whereas `Settings.settings` corresponds to java's `preferences`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: I'd like to add though that this is the Microsoft-esque approach; it's typically a lot easier and more dynamic to just use the XML serializer to read a specific file in the program folder directly. With that approach, you can even more easily write a small GUI tool to generate and modify these files.

Comment: @dialer thanks. I have implemented now in my own class, that I will transform into using XML files later on.

Answer (score 0):

if your application dynamically stores data and its huge then better way to sore it is Database table. 
if user dependent application setting data then you can use,

- External file(ex. MS EXCEL...)
- Configuration file of application.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serialization to store the parameter into registry.

Example:

You pass the String into Byte and serialize it.
When you are deserialize the information, you change the byte back to a string.

More you can find here..
[Save serializable object to registry in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579782/save-serializable-object-to-registry-in-net)

Maybe its an opportunity for you..